# Filtering children in a Nested JsonPath

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, jsonpath, rest-assured

I have to validate the following JSON :

```
{
    "data": {
    "children": [{
        "nodes": [{
            "key": "STATE",
            "value": "Alaska"
        }],
        "children": [{
            "nodes": [{
                "key": "STATE",
                "value": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "key": "NAME",
                "value": "Jack"
            }, {
                "key": "AGE",
                "value": "13"
            }]
        }, {
            "nodes": [{
                "key": "STATE",
                "value": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "key": "NAME",
                "value": "Jill"
            }, {
                "key": "AGE",
                "value": "23"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "nodes": [{
            "key": "STATE",
            "value": "Texas"
        }],
        "children": [{
            "nodes": [{
                "key": "STATE",
                "value": "Texas"
            }, {
                "key": "NAME",
                "value": "John"
            }, {
                "key": "AGE",
                "value": "23"
            }]
        }]
    }]
  }
}
```

There are two nested lists in the JSON first is grouped by "STATE" and it contains children list which hold values of Names. 
I need to find just the Names that are grouped as 'Alaska'.
I have tried the following JsonPath but, it returns null:

```
 $.data..children[?(@nodes.value == 'Alaska')].children[?(@nodes.key=='NAME').value
```

I haven't tried GPath (findAll) but, if it's a better solution, please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the inbuilt Groovy JsonSlurper...  Assuming your json is a string in the variable `jsonTxt`, you can just do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def names = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonTxt)
                             .data
                             .children
                             .find { 'Alaska' in it.nodes.value }
                             .children
                             .nodes
                             .flatten()
                             .findAll { it.key == 'NAME' }
                             .value

assert names == ['Jack', 'Jill']
```